# Is it possible to change a method's return type for the method chain?

Tags: java, reflection

I am implementing a method, myAssert(String s), it needs to behave like this,

condition1:  it can work with *isEqualTo(o)* in a way of ***myAssert("test").isEqualTo(someObj)*** to check if they are 2 equal objects

condition2: it can work with *startsWith(String s2)* in a way of ***myAssert("this is a string").startsWith("this is")***

Apparently myAssert needs to change its return type to be a string or an object. I know in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html or https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html there are APIs to get information in a class.

But is there any API I can use to retrieve the information about the method channing?

Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean 'information about the method chain'?  I'm not seeing why you need reflection for this at all.  You need to return a type which has an `isEqualTo` and `startsWith` method.  If you implement such a class, then have the `myAssert` method return that.

Comment: I see. I was thinking about a possible way to get an api to give me whether the later function call is startwith or equalto, so I can decide to return an object or a string. But I guess something like that doesn’t exist.

Comment: Java's a compiled language, so methods that you call need to exist and be identifiable from the source code.  There are JVM based languages (groovy springs to mind) which let you call arbitrary methods on things, which eventually resolve to a `getProperty` method, which takes the method name and arguments as arguments.  You could implement this in that sort of manner if you so choose.  But in plain java I think you're out of luck.